# Show vertical model list to horizontly for each date like Attendace register

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a attendance list of all student from a specific date to a end date.
but i have a data show like given beleow but i want to show this horizontly at front end. my code work fine for vertically reporting but i want to make it horizontally date wise.

```
SID N   A   C   Date
 1  S1  0   1   2015-04-20
 2  s2  1   1   2015-04-20
 3  s3  0   1   2015-04-20
 4  s4  1   1   2015-04-20
 5  s5  1   1   2015-04-20
 1  s1  0   1   2015-04-21
 2  s2  0   1   2015-04-21
 3  s3  0   1   2015-04-21
 4  s4  0   1   2015-04-21
 5  s5  0   1   2015-04-21
 1  s1  0   1   2015-04-22
 2  s2  1   1   2015-04-22
 3  s3  1   1   2015-04-22
 4  s4  1   1   2015-04-22
 5  s5  0   1   2015-04-22
 1  s1  0   1   2015-04-23
 2  s2  0   1   2015-04-23
 3  s3  1   1   2015-04-23
 4  s4  1   1   2015-04-23
 5  s5  0   1   2015-04-23
```

Code is :

```
var result = (from r in context.AllAttendances
              orderby r.Attend ascending
              where r.ClassId == model.SelectedBindClassDropdown
              select r).ToList();

List<ClassViewModel.AllStudentRow> model1 = new List<ClassViewModel.AllStudentRow>();

if (result.Any())
{
    foreach (var record in result)
    {
        var className = (
            from r in context.ClassTimes 
            where r.Id == record.ClassId 
            select new { className = r.Class })
            .FirstOrDefault();

        model1.Add(new ClassViewModel.AllStudentRow()
        {
            Id = record.Id,
            Name = record.Name,
            ClassName = className.className,
            ClassId = Convert.ToInt32(record.ClassId),
            Attend = Convert.ToInt32(record.Attend),
            time = Convert.ToDateTime(record.Date)
        });
    }

    model1 = model1.Where(stu => 
        stu.time >= Convert.ToDateTime(model.txtDate) && 
        stu.time <= Convert.ToDateTime(model.toDate)).ToList();

    obj.AllStudentRows = model1;
}
```

cshtml:

```
 <table>
        <tr>

            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class Name</th>
            <th>Attend</th>
            <th>Time</th>

        </tr>
        @if (Model.AllStudentRows != null)
        {
            foreach (var objUser in Model.AllStudentRows)
            {
            <tr>

                <td>@objUser.Name</td>
                <td>@objUser.ClassName</td>
                <td>
                    @if (@objUser.Attend == 0)
                    { <label style="color:red">Absent</label> }
                    else
                    {<label style="color:green">Present</label> }
                </td>
                <td>@objUser.time.ToShortDateString()</td>
            </tr>
            }
        }else{<tr><td colspan="4">No records for this date</td></tr>}

    </table>
```

My requirement is

```
Name | 20-04-2015 | 21-04-2015 | 22-0-2015 | 23-04-2015
s1       0             0            0            0
s2       1             0            1            0
s3       0             0            1            1
s4       1             0            1            1
s5       1             0            0            0
```

Let me know if anyone have some solution for this

Comment: Will it always be a fixed number of columns (i.e name plus 4 dates)

Comment: no its dynamic, like user give a start date(20-04-2015) to end (23-04-2015),

Comment: You would need a view model with properties (say) `string Name` and `List<int>Attend` then use a `GroupBy` statement to group by the name, and populate the collection based on the relative position of the date relative to the start date.

Comment: @StephenMuecke will you please tell me with some demo code. how can i do this

Comment: Sure, but give me a hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating view models that represent what you need to display

```
public class StudentVM
{
  public StudentVM(int days)
  {
    Attendance = new int[days];
  }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int[] Attendance { get; set; }
}

public class AttendanceVM
{
  public AttendanceVM(DateTime start, DateTime end)
  {
    int days = (end - start).Days;
    Dates = new DateTime[days];
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
      Dates[i] = start.AddDays[i];
    }
    Students  = new List<StudentVM>();
  }
  public DateTime[] Dates { get; set; }
  public List<StudentVM> Students { get; set; }
}
```

In the view

```
@model AttendanceVM
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      @foreach(var date in Model.Dates)
      {
        <th>@date</th>
      }
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var student in Model.Students)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@student.Name</td>
        @foreach (var attendance in student.Attendance)
        {
          <td>@attendance</td>
        }
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in the controller, group your data by the student

```
var result = (from r in context.AllAttendances
          orderby r.Attend ascending
          where r.ClassId == model.SelectedBindClassDropdown
          group r by r.Name into g
          select new { Name = g.Key, Values = g }));
```

Note: I suspect you really need to filter by date so assuming you are passing `startDate` and `endDate` to the method then it might be

```
where r.ClassId == model.SelectedBindClassDropdown && r.Date > startDate && r.Date < endDate
```

Then initialize your view model and return it to the view

```
int days = (endDate - startDate).Days;
var model = new AttendanceVM(startDate, endDate);
foreach (var item in result)
{
  StudentVM student = new StudentVM(days);
  student.Name = item.Name;
  foreach(var value in item.Values)
  {
    int index = (value.Date - startDate).Days;
    student.Attendance[index] = value.Attend;
  }
  model.Students.Add(student);
}
return View(model);
```

Comment: int index = (value.Date - todate).`Days`; 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Days' and no extension method 'Days' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is you Date property nullable? If so then use `value.Date.Value` But why on earth would you have a nullable date in a database?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display "no record" if record not exists, you can try

```
var dates = result.Select(x => x.Date).Distinct();
var res = result.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            AttendanceList = dates.Select(d => new 
            {
                Date = d,
                Attendance = x.Where(y=> y.Date == d).Select( y=> y.Attend.ToString()).FirstOrDefault() ?? "No record"
            })
        });
```

Comment: all name show in list but in attendance list a error shows:
AttendanceList {System.Linq.Enumerable.Where SelectEnumerableIterator<System.DateTime?,<>f__AnonymousType6<System.DateTime?,string>>}

Comment: Is your Date field nullable? [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SAxnBV) you can see working example.

Comment: will you please help to bind this list at front end?

Comment: Please past your AllStudentRow model :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75779/discussion-between-sandeep-singh-and-marcin-j).